# Unknown meaning of colon ( : ) in assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly

I'm using a disassembler (SmartDec: http://decompilation.info/) and the many of the instructions in the generated disassembly look similar to this:

```
mov rax, [rip + 0x32b5]:64
```

I'm unfamiliar with the `:64` part of this instruction. What does it mean?

Other examples:

```
cmp [rcx + r8 * 0x8]:64, 0x0
mov eax, [rip + 0x592a]:32
jmp [rip + 0x6bad]:64
```

This disassembler doesn't show the corresponding machine code, so I used a hex editor and looked up the address that it said this instruction was at:

```
1665:   mov rax, [rip + 0x19a4]:64
```

This is what was there, 16 bytes worth, in Little Endian:

```
54 00 00 49 89 E8 FF 15 DC 5F 00 00 E9 57 FF FF
```

Comment: SmartDec is the disassembler, http://decompilation.info/

Comment: I don't think you got the right hex bytes for that instruction.  I don't see `a4` or `19` bytes in the machine code anywhere.  Maybe your disassembler doesn't really mean RIP+ that, and it really means the absolute address is `0x19a4`, addressed relative to RIP.  But anyway, `54` is not an opcode for `mov`.  [`49 89 ...` is REX.W=1 `mov r/m64, r64` (a store)](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/MOV), unless those bytes are part of (not the start of) another instruction.  I'd recommend using another disassembler (like `objdump -drwC -Mintel`) for comparison in future.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the size of the memory operand, printed for whatever reason. I have deduced it from an [example on the SmartDec home page](http://decompilation.info/sites/decompilation.info/files/ValidateImageBase_0.png) which reads as `movzx edx, [ecx]:16` As such this is just the equivalent to what would be `movzx edx, word [ecx]` in other assemblers (or `word ptr`). It is only useful if the size can not be deduced from the other operand, as in this `movzx` case. `SmartDec` seems to be showing it every time though, e.g. for your example in the question, `mov rax, [rip + 0x32b5]:64` it's clear that the size is 64 bits so it's not helping much.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wonder why they decided to do it that way instead of the well accepted way?

Comment: @SeanRamey looks to me as shortest way (`:16` vs `word `), and still well readable for me, also colon is often used together with bit counts, or bits manipulation, so it's not completely shocking to me... as far as I'm concerned, I don't mind this new (for me) notation (contrary to other stunts I have seen, like asmGo I think, or something like that). ... anyway "why" => "why not"? There was never too strong standard of x86 assembly, Intel keeps it somewhat consistent through docs, but it's not usable for writing source as is, and the assemblers always kept defining the missing pieces.